# How to split a huge file into words?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

How can I read a very long string from text file, and then process it (split into words)?

I tried the `StreamReader.ReadLine()` method, but I get an `OutOfMemory` exception. Apparently, my lines are extremely long.
This is my code for reading file:

```
using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(_filePath))
    {

        int lineNumber = 1;
        string currentString = String.Empty;
        while ((currentString = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            ProcessString(currentString, lineNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Line {0}", lineNumber);
            lineNumber++;
        }
    }
```

And the code which splits line into words:

```
var wordPattern = @"\w+";
var matchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, wordPattern);
var words = (from Match word in matchCollection
             select word.Value.ToLowerInvariant()).ToList();
```

Comment: What algorithm/method have you used for the splitting operation?

Comment: @byako, here is method which I use for this: `public static IEnumerable<string> GetLowercasedWords(string text)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                return null;
            }
            var wordPattern = @"\w+";
            var matchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, wordPattern);
            var words = (from Match word in matchCollection
                         select word.Value.ToLowerInvariant()).ToList();

            return words;
        }` Sorry for formatting.

Comment: Better add how you actually implemented the StreamReader as well, so people may find errors there. There is no 140 character limit for questions.

Comment: @Jens, sure,  I added code to my question

Comment: Please add your use case, e.g. what are you doing with the words, do you want to count occurrences, get the unique list of words, etc ? It could provide further optimization possibilities

Comment: Does the exception occurs, If you replace the split line process by a simple text.Substring(0,Math.Max(10,text.length)) ?

Comment: @Bas, Sure, I need to split line into words and write this words into another file with list of lines where this word occurs.

Comment: Then I'll leave it to you to alter my method to read by line.

Comment: I'd take the `ToList()` out of the `GetLowercasedWords`. I can't see how it does anything other than take up memory, slow things down, and risk out of memory errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could read by char, building up words as you go, using `yield` to make it deferred so you don't have to read the entire file at once:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ReadWords(string filename)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            char c = (char)reader.Read();

            // Mimics regex /w/ - almost.
            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '_')
            {
                builder.Append(c);
            }
            else
            {
                if (builder.Length > 0)
                {
                    yield return builder.ToString();
                    builder.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        yield return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

The code reads the file by character, and when it encounters a non-word character it will `yield return` the word built up until then (only for the first non-letter character). The code uses a `StringBuilder` to build the word string.

[`Char.IsLetterOrDigit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit(v=vs.110).aspx) behaves just as [the regex word character `w`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#WordCharacter) for characters, but underscores (amongst others) also fall into the latter category. If your input contains more characters you also wish to include, you'll have to alter the `if()`.

Comment: Wouldn't `StringBuilder` be a better option for this approach?

Comment: Be careful! This is not the equivalent of `\w+` as it does not handle anything except whitespace (e.g. dashes, punctuation).

Comment: `\w` also includes digits and underscore.

Comment: In this case word is sequence of [A-Za-z0-9]

Comment: This works but the CPU load will be enormous. Char-by-char processing is really expensive. Update: This does 30MB per second which is a lot more than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Cut it into bit size sections. So that instead of trying to read 4gb, which I believe is about the size of a page, try to read 8 500mb chunks and that should help.

Comment: I should say that you aren't going to split it in precise chunks. But relatively close enough chunks. The reason I say that is because if you have a 500 mb cutoff you would want to split the file apart at the end or start of a word, not the middle. So don't just cut up the file. Do it in a smarter manner.

Comment: you`re right. And that is the main reason why I encountered difficulties

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection may be a solution. I am not really sure that it is the problem source. But if it is the case, a simple GC.Collect is often unsufficient and, for performance reason, it should only be called if really required. Try the following procedure that calls the garbage when the available memory is too low (below the threshold provided as procedure parameter).

```
int charReadSinceLastMemCheck = 0 ;
using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(_filePath))
{

    int lineNumber = 1;
    string currentString = String.Empty;
    while ((currentString = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        ProcessString(currentString, lineNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Line {0}", lineNumber);
        lineNumber++;
        totalRead+=currentString.Length ;
        if (charReadSinceLastMemCheck>1000000) 
        { // Check memory left every Mb read, and collect garbage if required
          CollectGarbage(100) ;
          charReadSinceLastMemCheck=0 ;
        } 
    }
}


internal static void CollectGarbage(int SizeToAllocateInMo)
{
       long [,] TheArray ;
       try { TheArray =new long[SizeToAllocateInMo,125000]; }low function 
       catch { TheArray=null ; GC.Collect() ; GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() ; GC.Collect() ; }
       TheArray=null ;
}
```

Comment: @CodeCaster: you wrote in your removed comment "You also shouldn't cross-post voodoo-code that you found on some French forum". If it is against StackOverflow principles to duplicate code that you already posted in another forum, I will quickly leave the forum. If you look at the author of the french forum response, you will see that its name is also "Graffito". But you surely think its another guy.

Comment: Graffito, your CollectGarbage method is the devil. I recognize it from your earlier answer.