# OutofMemory exception in C# dll calling from Cpp Application

Tags: c#, c++, out-of-memory

I Have a one big 32bit application implemented in CPP. This c++ application call another .net dll implemented in c# using COM interface. 
After some function calls from c++ to c# I get OutOfMemory exception in .net dll. This could be due to fact that I have to allocate some very large List having more than 3000 object references. But the problem is that when I analyse that memory consumption of the process in Windows Task Manager the memory consumption is only 800 MB while it could have gone upto 2 GB.

So the question is what could be the reason that without consuming the full process space why am I getting memory consumption ?
Is there any memory limitation for the .net dll due to which it is getting limited memory ?
How can I increase the memory allocated to .net dll so that heap size can be larger?

Comment: Could we see the code?

Comment: .NET applications are limited to about 1.3GB - is it possible you measured 800mb after it crashed? It will quickly free up memory usage once an error occurs.

Comment: The .net garbage collector is imperfect when there is a sufficient amount of available memory, but splitted in small segments. In such case, you may need to force the garbage collection. For calling the GC, Refer to the CollectGarbage() function in my response to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256036/how-to-split-a-huge-file-into-words).